# Client side MVC plus media responsive UI

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, ember.js, javascript-framework

I m still new to client side MVC and at this point exploring my options.
Angular.js, Ember.js both are highly recommended frameworks, backbone.js is a library but most of the implementation user has to do.
Need a opinion from someone who has been working in client side MVC, as to how should one decide which one to go for?

Plus I need the UI to be media responsive, for which twitter Bootstrap looks ideal.
Is it possible to use one of these framework along with Twitter Bootstrap? In which framework is it easier to integrate Bootstrap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs and Bootstrap are the two which I would start with.

AngularJS is opinionated, this means it will help you structure your code well. If you just want binding then don't forget knockoutjs. This is in the mvc package by default in VS.

Bootstrap is just html and css markup so should work with everything.

If you start a MVC5 project now in VS2013 you will by standard have bootstrap.

Many people will have different opinions on this so you could wait for an answer for a long time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I believe the community support plus demo example to learn from are also more readily available for angular, but definitely i want to dig a little more on ember too. In case in you are aware of any good site for references (for either of them) then please do share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I understand your confusion when it comes to selecting the right JavaScript framework**. There are many deciding factors that you must evaluate before dedicating your time and money. I noticed that you mentioned a MVC in your questions title. The first thing that you will want to understand is exactly which MV* architecture that you want to have for your app and why. Once you have that nailed down then selecting the framework will be much easier since you will have eliminated a few of the frameworks. The four architectures are MVC, MVVM, MVP and MV*. Another major factor that you will want to look at is the binding mechanism used for the framework. Some frameworks only allow one way bindings while others support 2-way bindings.

**To answer your question, based on what you have explained, I would say that Ember is going to be your best bet. Ember will work with Bootstrap**

http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/dist/

If your still researching the facts then you will really want to check out this helpful link to a page that goes over the pros and cons of the most popular JS frameworks.

Check it out here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/